# Custom Validation Annotation introduces ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, seam, concurrentmodification

I was tasked with creating an Annotation for Custom Validation. This was due to some problems with [handling database constraint violations nicely.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25737951/handling-database-constraint-errors-nicely) What I did in response to this was *relatively* simple. I created a class-level CustomConstraint specifically for the one domain-class that required it. What I got as my current result is the following:

**@UniqueLocation Annotation:**

```java
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueLocationValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface UniqueLocation {

    String message() default "must be unique!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

This is not spectacular, in fact it's copied almost verbatim from the [hibernate documentation.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html)

I proceeded to create my `UniqueLocationValidator` and ran into a problem with using the persistence context in there. I wanted to run a defensive select, and thusly tried to Inject my application wide `@Produces @PersistenceContext EntityManager`.

Therefor I included JBoss Seam to use it's `InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory` configuring my validation.xml as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-config 
   xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration validation-configuration-1.0.xsd">

   <constraint-validator-factory>
      org.jboss.seam.validation.InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory
   </constraint-validator-factory>

</validation-config>
```

After running into some issues with [Creating Constraint Violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997520/addpropertynode-equivalent-in-version-1-0) this is how my Validator actually looks:

```java
@ManagedBean
public class UniqueLocationValidator implements
        ConstraintValidator<UniqueLocation, Location> {
    // must not return a result for name-equality on the same Id
    private final String QUERY_STRING = "SELECT * FROM Location WHERE locationName = :value AND id <> :id";

    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    private String constraintViolationMessage;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final UniqueLocation annotation) {
        constraintViolationMessage = annotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Location instance,
            final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            // Recommended, instead use explicit @NotNull Annotation for
            // validating non-nullable instances
            return true;
        }

        if (duplicateLocationExists(instance)) {
            createConstraintViolations(context);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void createConstraintViolations(
            final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(constraintViolationMessage)
                .addNode("locationName").addConstraintViolation();
    }

    private boolean duplicateLocationExists(final Location location) {
        final String checkedValue = location.getLocationName();
        final long id = location.getId();

        Query defensiveSelect = entityManager.createNativeQuery(QUERY_STRING)
                .setParameter("value", checkedValue).setParameter("id", id);

        return !defensiveSelect.getResultList().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

So much for my current configuration, now to the real beef, the problem:

When I run following code after recieving an action from a user, the thing works wonderfully and correctly marks a duplicate location name as invalid.. Also persisting works just fine when the locationName is not duplicated.

```java
public long add(@Valid final Location location) {
    entityManager.persist(location);
    return location.getId();
}
```

Mind that the `entityManager` here and the `entityManager` in the UniqueLocationValidator are both injected via Weld CDI from the aforementioned @PersistenceContext EntityManager.

What does not work is the following:

```java
public long update(@Valid final Location location){
    entityManager.merge(location);
    return location.getId();
}
```

When calling this code, I get a relatively short stacktrace, that has a `ConcurrentModificationException` as root-cause.

I neither understand why that's the case, nor how I would go about fixing this. I have nowhere attempted to explicitly multithread my application, so this should have been managed by the JBoss 7.1.1-Final I am using as application server..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible via the `EntityManager`. Well, not normally.

Your validator is called during the processing of the updates. Queries sent via the `EntityManager` affect the internal storage, the `ActionQueue` of the `EntityManager`. This is what causes the `ConcurrentModificationException`: the results from your query alter the list that the `EntityManager` is iterating through when flushing changes.

A workaround for this would be to bypass the `EntityManager`.

How can we do this?

Well, ... it's a bit dirty, since you're effectively adding a dependency on the hibernate implementation, but you can [get the connection from the Session or EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482731/how-to-get-jdbc-connection-from-hibernate-session) in various ways. And once you have a `java.sql.Connection` object, well, you can use something like a `PreparedStatement` to execute your query anyway.

---

Example fix:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementation = (SessionFactoryImplementor) session.getSessionFactory();
ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = sessionFactoryImplementation.getConnectionProvider();
try {
       connection = connectionProvider.getConnection();
       PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT 1 FROM Location WHERE id <> ? AND locationName = ?");
       ps.setLong(1, id);
       ps.setString(2, checkedValue);
       ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
       boolean result = rs.next();//found any results? if we can retrieve a row: yes!
       rs.close();
       return result;
}//catch SQLException etc... 
//finally, close resources (only the resultset!)
```